# Using PCI Geomatica 2016?

Tags: error, imagery, image, geomatica

I've been experiencing some trouble when inserting some optical satellite imagery into PCI Geomatica 2016 (Trial version).

Whenever I open my .TIL file, an X appears beside its name in the Focus' Maps tab and some parts of the image appear to have disappeared in several places of the original image.

Answer (score 1):

The red X means that the file is read only which is expected when you open a .TIL file.

The missing tiles is a bug that have since been addressed. I would recommend that test it in the latest version of focus.